# RSpec, Spork & Postgres Error: prepared statement “a1” already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rspec2

In our PostgreSQL-backed Rails project, when running rspec using spork, sometimes we receive the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  prepared statement "a1" already exists
```

Originally, it occurred only a few times a day, but recently, it has begun happening every 3-4 test runs which slows our development efforts to a crawl.

Is there a way to reset/delete the prepared statements in PostgreSQL somewhere inside of our `spec_helper.rb` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-deallocate.html) and a fair amount of trial and error testing it in different spots inside the `spec_helper.rb`, I finally figured out that I could add the following to delete all existing prepared statements and I have not since seen the error:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ... other code

  config.after(:suite) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DEALLOCATE ALL")
  end

  # ... other code
end
```

Comment: That seems like a bit of a kludge that is hiding the real problem. Something isn't cleaning up after itself and sloppily assuming that everything will be okay once the database connection is closed. You're adding a kludge to your test suite to hide an error, that's a bit dodgy.

Comment: @muistooshort I'd love to hear any suggestions, but since we're not actually using prepared statements, I don't know what isn't properly cleaning up after itself. I'm assuming this is something in the Rails internals that creates prepared statements for performance purposes.

Comment: What database libraries are you using? Just plain ActiveRecord?

Comment: @muistooshort Just plain ActiveRecord right now, although we are using DatabaseCleaner and I know we've had some problems with it (particularly, I couldn't get it working with any Javascript examples, so those are cleaning up after themselves). Thanks for the pointers/help! I'd love to fix this the right way :-)

Comment: I'll dig around this evening and see if I can figure out how the Rails PostgreSQL adapter uses prepared statements.

Comment: I haven't tried to duplicate this a lot, but I *seem* to be getting this only when I am run the dev server, guard (with spork) and maybe have a console open.  I assume that somehow a combination of all of these is the source. Just running guard by itself won't cause this issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's intriguing...I'll keep an eye out for that, although we don't use guard, so I'm not sure if this is just a console issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can get this if you're doing something like:

```
  class ActiveRecord::Base
    mattr_accessor :shared_connection
    @@shared_connection = nil
    def self.connection
      @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
    end
  end
  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

(which was recommended [here](https://gist.github.com/470808)).

If you have that or similar, try removing it.

Comment: I am not doing that. I tried it at one point, but could never get our JavaScript specs working right.